# Debugging formula

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, excel-formula

I am trying to debug my code here which basically inserts a formula. however, there is an error in the formula line. can you help me debug it. it says

> error  1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If c.Value = "Max" Then
c.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=concatenate(concatenate(left" & c.Address(False, False) & ",3)" & ",""-""," & "right(" & c.Address(False, False) & ",3))" & ","":""," & c.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False) & ")"
end if
next
```

Comment: That instruction is doing two things: 1) determine what formula to use, and 2) assigning a specific cell's formula. Split it in two distinct instructions - introduce a local variable, e.g. `Dim theFormula As String`, assign it, e.g. `theFormula = "=concatenate(concatenate(left" & c.Address(False, False) & ",3)" & ",""-""," & "right(" & c.Address(False, False) & ",3))" & ","":""," & c.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False) & ")"`, and then do `c.Offset(0, 3).Formula = theFormula` but before that add `Debug.Print theFormula` and add a breakpoint. Look at the debug output, fix accordingly.

Comment: you are a hero. your instructions helped me fixed it. Thank you so much